# Recursive map works, but recursive unordered_map doesn't

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap, g++, unordered-map

I was wondering, why does this code compile just fine with g++,

```cpp
struct FileSystemMap {
    std::map<std::string, FileSystemMap> directories;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> files;
};
```

while this other doesn't?

```cpp
struct FileSystemMap {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, FileSystemMap> directories;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> files;
};
```

Comment: Please show the verbatim error message you get.

Comment: Because the error blob I get is so long (7 Kb) that stackoverflow doesn't let me paste it (it tells me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."). You should just try my two lines of code.

Comment: Fair enough, template error messages can be long. Basically, both your snippets are invalid, regardless of whether they produce an error or not. The linked target covers this; it's UB in general, unless a container explicitly says it's allowed. Neither `map` nor `unordered_map` allow it.

Comment: some implementations of unordered map designed the way that they abstract themselves from contained type by type erasure. Which clearly impossible with `map`. It's better to employ type erasure pattern yourself for unordered and use  PIMPL if needed , for ordered..